# Output words in a line in reverse order using awk

Tags: awk

How to output a line in reverse order using `awk`? I use this construction:

```
{
 for (i = NF; i > 1; i--){
 print $i
}
}
```

but it print just one word in one string.

Before:

```
apple pen dog cat
```

After:

```
cat dog pen apple
```

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/336149/315749 - with respect to AWK, though, [the accepted answer below](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/594683/315749) is better finished off.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
awk '
    {
        for (i=NF; i>=1; i--) {
            printf "%s%s", $i, i == 1 ? ORS : OFS
        }
     }
' file
```

Comment: Note that it removes blank lines.

Answer (score 5):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) lane:

```
perl -lane 'print join " ", reverse @F' file
```

Answer (score 2):

A variant that swaps the fields around in the current record before printing it (would use the current value of `OFS` for the output field separator if this is set on the command line (with `-v`) or elsewhere in the `awk` code).

```
$ awk '{ for (i = 1; i < NF/2; ++i) { t = $i; $i = $(NF-i+1); $(NF-i+1) = t } }; 1' file
cat dog pen apple
```

Just the `awk` code, with an explicit `print` instead of the shorthand `1` condition invoking the default action:

```c
{
    for (i = 1; i < NF/2; ++i) {
        # swap $i and $(NF-i+1)
        t = $i
        $i = $(NF-i+1)
        $(NF-i+1) = t
    }

    print
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with this question as posed. First of all, your code

```
{
 for (i = NF; i > 1; i--){
 print $i
}
}
```

is *syntactically* correct but *semantically* incorrect. That is, the code will run without errors (GNU Awk 5.0.1), but it doesn't do what you intend it to do (reverse the order of fields in a record). Furthermore, your explanation of the error:

> but it print just one word in one string.

is valid only for the case where the number of fields is equal to 2, given this code and this example text. That is, the input `apple pen` will indeed return only one word, `pen`. However, if you use the example `apple pen dog cat`, you will instead get:

```
cat
dog
pen
```

clearly showing that it prints more than just one word.

This output exposes two problems with this code:

1. Your loop `for( initialization; condition; incrementation )` is initialized and incremented properly, but the condition is wrong. It should rather be `i >= 1` or  `i > 0`. You can see this above, where the multi-word output is missing `apple`, because the first field (`apple`) is equal to 1 and the condition becomes false.
2. This print statement `... { print $i } ...` will output each *field* as an individual *record* or line. This is because the default behavior of `{ print }`,  or here `{ print $N }` is to output a *record* or line.

   > **Printing Every Line**
   >
   > If an action has no pattern, the action is performed for all input lines. The statement `print` by itself prints the current input line, so the program
   >
   > `{ print }`
   >
   > prints all of its input on the standard output. Since `$0` is the whole line,
   >
   > `{ print $0 }`
   >
   > does the same thing.

   (The Awk Programming Language, p. 5, 1988)

   This is why the code is printing each *field* (word) as a new *record* (line).

Assuming:

1. Your input *fields* (words) are separated by one or more whitespace characters,
2. Your input *records* are separated by a newline,
3. You want your output fields separated by a single space, and
4. You want your output records separated by a newline

The canonical answer, from "The Awk Programming Language" (p. 18, 1988) should suffice, and as a bonus is simpler to understand than the other answers:

```bash
awk '{ for (i = NF; i > 0; i = i - 1) printf("%s ", $i); printf("\n") }' FILE
```

This should also preserve blank *records*.

A reminder from page 8:

> With printf, no blanks or newlines are produced automatically; you must create them yourself. Don't forget the \n.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `awk`, and preserving the original spacing between the fields:

```
gawk -v FPAT='[[:space:]]+|[^[:space:]]+' -v ORS= '
   {for (i = NF; i > 0; i--) print $i; print RT}'
```

On a `" foo bar  baz"` input, it outputs `"baz  bar foo "`.

That assumes the input is correctly encoded text in the locale.

Beware that if the input uses MS-DOS line delimiters, you'll end up with lines starting with carriage return characters (possibly preceded with more whitespace). You may need to pass a `-v RS='\r?\n'`  to accommodate those.